# SSL Problem, Where should I insert the certificate.crt?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I'm using startSSL. I've got a private key.key, a certificate.crt and a decrypted key.key for private key.key. What should I do with this files and where should I upload them? How can I get https for my website?

p.s.  I'm using a free web host. So I can't submit tickets for additional help, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache check your httpd.conf and/or ssl.conf and add the appropriate lines.

from httpd.conf:

```
##SSL
SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/example.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/certs/intermediate.crt
```

from ssl.conf

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/example.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/certs/intermediate.crt
```

**Make sure permissions are correct!!**
Permissions from /etc/certs:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.7K Oct  8 04:26 example.com.crt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.1K Oct  8 04:15 example.com.csr
-rw-------   1 root root 1.7K Oct  8 04:35 example.com.key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5K Jul 27 19:20 intermediate.crt
```

Other server configs can be found here:
https://www.startssl.com/?app=20

Comment: Ok, now I have 5 files: private key.key, decrypted key.key, certificate.crt, httpd.conf and ssl.conf. Where should I place all this files? On public_html? Or what should I do with this files? P.s.: the last two files was edited for my case. Thanks for answering and sorry for my insistently questions.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I use windows but the server - I don't know.

Comment: I'm using a free shard host( cpanel.freehosting.io ). I think that I'm not able to activate a security certificate on a shared free hosting. Here is an image of my cpanel: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8tSeu.png .

Comment: I have found some information about the server: http://s27.postimg.org/jwa5yucv7/IMG_20151012_235034.jpg

Comment: Nevermind! I used cloudflare for https( flexible certificate). It's better and very very simple to activate. However, thank you very much!

Comment: Normally your **/etc/httpd/conf** will contain the **httpd.conf** file and **/etc/httpd/conf.d** will contain the **ssl.conf** where you need these entries placed. For the cert files themselves I personally use **/etc/certs**.